# Как получить результат SQL запроса?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

выполняю вот такой запрос

```
const QString queryStr = QString::fromLatin1("SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM 
Calen WHERE Date ='%1'").arg(maindate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

QSqlQuery mainquery(queryStr);
mainquery.exec();
```

Как узнать не пустой ли запрос получился в итоге?  или как узнать количество строк в нем ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Для этого существует метод `QSqlQuery::next()`:

```
while (mainquery.next()) 
{
    //Здесь получаете Ваши данные
}
```

Если в ответе нет записей, то цикл `while` не выполнится ни разу, в противном случае он выполнится столько раз, сколько строк должно быть возвращено.

Кстати, у Вас в коде вопиющая ошибка, которая может привести к SQL-инъекции. Правильно привязывать параметры запроса нужно так:

```
QSqlQuery mainquery;
mainquery.prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM Calen WHERE Date=:date");
mainquery.bindValue(":date", maindate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
if(mainquery.exec())
{
    while (mainquery.next()) 
    {
        //Здесь получаете Ваши данные
    }
}
```

Comment: Неверно. Узнать пустой ли запрос можно и нужно двумя путями: 1) проверив результат `.query()` (обязательно!) и 2) методом `.size()`. P.S. интересно, кто и на каком основании удаляет комментарии к вопросу...

Comment: @PinkTux, что конкретно в моём ответе не верно?

Comment: Так написал же: 1) не проверяется результат `.exec()` - sorry, опечатался и 2) количество строк проверяется методом `.size()` (можно и сразу начать шагать по ним, но метод .next()` всё-таки именно для перемещения предназначен, а не для того, что было в вопросе).

Comment: @PinkTux, то, что нет проверки результата выполнения `exec()` — это безусловно ошибка, спасибо, я её исправлю. А что касается `size()`, то Вы неправы. В документации написано, что этот метод зависит от DB. Я только что [посмотрел реализацию](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp.html#_ZN13QSQLiteResult4sizeEv) для SQLite и она возвращает -1.